# Trying to do a left join merge in R but want to select specific columns. Receiving error message

Tags: r, join, merge

Both unique_id for x and y are chr data types. Both are spelled the same exact way.
When i run the script like here it works. However I don't want to join all values. I want to join specific values.

```
results2<-merge(x=results2, y=machine, by = "SR_Num", all.x= TRUE)
```

However when i want to select the two specific columns as specified below. I get an error message.

```
results2<-merge(x=results2, y=machine[ , c("narrative", "date")], by = "unique_id",all.x=TRUE)
```

The error message says

```
Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Comment: Change to: `y=machine[ , c("unique_id", "narrative", "date")]`

Comment: To expand on @DanY's answer: `y=` is the frame that `merge` "sees", so while `machine$unique_id` exists, merge only knows about `y`, and `y$unique_id` does not exist when you use `y=machine[,c("narrative","date")]`.

Comment: @DanY Perfect. This worked immediately.